# has written / did write / wrote in questions

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

I have this (incorrect) sentence: “How many plays has William Shakespeare written?”. How does it need to be corrected and why exactly:

- How many plays did William Shakespeare write?
- How many plays William Shakespeare wrote?
- How many plays wrote William Shakespeare?

Comment: Tell us a bit more about your thinking please :) (Edit your question) Some things you could tell us: Which of the answers do you think is correct and why? Can you discard one of the options? Why is the original question wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike the other European languages I know, the present perfect is not the most common tense to use in English to describe past actions or states. It is used in special circumstances. For a brief introduction to a subtle issue in English grammar, see

[https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/present-perfect-or-past-simple.html#:~:text=What%27s%20the%20difference%3F%20Present%20Perfect%20and%20Past%20Simple,week%2C%20la%20...%20%201%20more%20rows%20](https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/present-perfect-or-past-simple.html#:%7E:text=What%27s%20the%20difference%3F%20Present%20Perfect%20and%20Past%20Simple,week%2C%20la%20...%20%201%20more%20rows%20)

This is not one of the special cases where the present perfect is appropriate.

In English, we normally form questions using an auxiliary verb followed by the subject and ending with the bare infinitive of the meaningful verb.

> Shall we go to the movies?

> Must I do my homework right now?

If the question is about the past and in the active voice, the auxiliary verb is “did.”

> Did he eat the entire cake?

This is an inversion of normal word order.

If, however, we introduce a question with “how many,” we specify how many of what before dealing with the inverted verb and subject.

> How many cakes did he buy?

Therefore the first option is correct.

**WARNING** Questions where some form of “be” is the operative verb do not use “did” as an auxiliary to indicate a question about the past.

> Was the cake good?

> How many cakes was he carrying?

Comment: > Questions where some form of “be” is the operative verb do not use “did”

Yes, I didn’t pay attention to it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

William Shakespeare is dead, so the problem is that it speaks about him in the present tense.

It should be:

> How many plays **did** William Shakespeare **write**?

You could say of a living person:

> He *has* written twelve plays *and he is currently working on two more*.

Comment: Why not “How many plays William Shakespeare wrote”?

Comment: Because that isn't how a question is written.

Comment: @danya because you're missing a verb. If you were making a statement, you'd only need one verb, ie "Shakespeare wrote plays". But when you ask a question, the question needs a verb, ie "what *is*", "who *are*", "why *does*", etc.

Comment: @Astralbee oh, now I see. Thanks!